# If a "Dr." signs their email with the first letter of their first name, is it acceptable to address them by their first name?

Tags: interviewing, email, networking

I recently made a contact for a potential job offer, and I have been addressing him with the "Dr." (he holds a doctorate). Let's say his name is "George McKee", then on his blog, website, and LinkedIn, he is referred to as "Dr. George McKee". I have been addressing him as "Dr. McKee" in our emails, and I noticed that he signs his name with a "g" (for "George") at the end of his emails. Does this mean I can/should call him "George"?

We have not met in person, but most people that know him call him "George".

Also, I am located in the United States, West Coast / Pacific North West

**Update**

Most of the answers/comments here are right in that I am over-thinking the situation. Perhaps I'm a bit socially anxious around well-educated or professionally accomplished people, as I've never known one personally. I'm the first in my family to venture into the "white-collar" or "college-educated" world, and I haven't had any mentors that understand this problem. I'm just trying to learn the etiquette without sounding robotic/awkward. Hopefully others will find this useful.

Comment: Do you prefer mrNiceGuy or may we call you NiceGuy. We're all friends here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to address a Dr. who I just met, when others address them by first name?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-address-a-dr-who-i-just-met-when-others-address-them-by-first-name)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're complicating your life. Call him "Dr McKee" until he explicitly tells you otherwise. You say that most people who know him call him "George"- Are you claiming that you know him based on the one or two emails that you sent him? If you do, you can call him "George".

Comment: "Absolute is the right of any man to spell his name 'Jones' and have it pronounced 'Smith'." If you want to know whether it's OK to call him George, ask him how he'd prefer to be addressed.

Comment: @keshlam You will address me as "Mr. Rat" :)

Comment: @Mr.Rat: Are you really sure you want to make that request? :-P

Comment: @keshlam Euh Oh - the name looks gorgeous, though. The rat is one of the animals in the Vietnamese calendar :)

Comment: @Vietnhi For non-technical communication, someone told me it's about how you say it, rather than what you say. It's a bit trickier in email/electronic communication, but I'll try to remember that advice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mrNiceGuy "Every boy is good looking in the eyes of his mother" is a pretty innocuous statement, except that I said it 30 years ago to Ravi, a fellow graduate student from the Chem Eng Dept of Columbia School of Engineering, as a couple of pretty coeds passed right by us, and I said it to him with a smirk. To make a long story short, it took five guys to pry Ravi's fingers loose from my throat. Thus, I conclude with a high degree of confidence from my unbiased if unintended testing that whoever told you that it's not what you say so much as how you say it - that whoever is totally right :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on your location, it's simply a matter of manners which are bound by countries and locations.

Where I come from you never address anyone with their last-name, but then again in other countries you never address anyone with their first-name, unless you know the person well enough to do so or that person has personally asked you to use his first name.

The latter option is defiantly the safe way to handle this situation, if you're not sure, use his last-name until he asks you not to.

Have you asked any of those people you know what he prefers others to call himself? They have experience with him, take an advantage of that:

*Hey, I'm going to meet George, do you know what he prefer strangers to call him?*